# Convert text file to python list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a python list from text file and this is my try

```
my_file = open("Sample.txt", "r")
content_list = my_file.readlines().replace('\n','')
print(content_list)
```

Solved

```
mylist = open('Sample.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
print(mylist)
```

Comment: Your code should result in an AttributeError because lists do not have a replace method.

Comment: Please delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip method.

If strip doesn't work then follow below approach

Use str.splitlines() to split your document into lines without newlines; you can rejoin it if you want to:

doclines = doc.splitlines()
doc_rejoined = ''.join(doclines)